# Camel and CXF: How to get the outbound message?

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf

I have this camel route:

```
    from("cxf:bean:endpointDocs01?loggingFeatureEnabled=true")
    .to("direct:CBR") 
    .transform().method(WebServiceUtils.class,"response()")
    .log("Outbound message: ${body}");
```

**endpointDocs01** is defined in the blueprint like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/documentos/" id="endpointDocs01"
    serviceClass="com.adelco.webservice.ServiceDocs" wsdlURL="wsdl/wsdl03.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

This route works with no problems including the schema-validation.

When I send a correct request, I can do "things" (in this case logging) using the last line of the exchange "**.log("Outbound message: ${body}**". In this case, the log shows this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <outputDocumento xmlns="http://webservice.adelco.com">
         <respuesta>0</respuesta>
         <mensaje>El mensaje [113282] fue recibido. Fecha recepción Wed Apr 12 17:01:11 CLT 2017</mensaje>
       </outputDocumento>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But, when I send a incorrect request, the line ".log("Log outbound message: ${body}" does nothing. However I get a response in the client (a Soap:Fault response)

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
          <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
          <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Sociedad'. One of '{"http://webservice.adelco.com":TipoMovimiento}' is expected.</faultstring>
       </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Why this soap:Fault response in not logged?

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by capture? CXF has features for logging input and output which you can turn on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route is invoked **after** unmarshalling. So if unmarshalling fails because of invalid input, the route does not trigger and does not log.

Read this article about [CXF architecture](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/cxf-architecture.html#CXFArchitecture-Messaging&Interceptors).

> **Phase Interceptors**
>   CXF provides an InterceptorChain implementation called the PhaseInterceptorChain. [...]
>   Let us take a hypothetical simplified example (NOTE: these phases and interceptors don't necessarily exist in CXF). Let us say we are parsing a SOAP message. We may want to have two phases. First, a dispatch phase which parses the soap headers and determines which service to route the Message to. Second, an unmarshal phase which binds the SOAP body to JAXB objects.
>   **Fault Handling**
>   At any point during processing, an interceptor may throw a Fault, or a derivative of a Fault like the SoapFault. This will cause the chain to stop invoking and unwind it. Unwinding consists of calling handleFault on each interceptor that was invoked in reverse order.

When a Fault occurs the processing is stopped and the interceptor chain unwinded. CXF uses different chains for messages (in & out) and Faults (in & out).

To use custom beans (which must implement `PhaseInterceptor` interface) as interceptors:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/documentos/" id="endpointDocs01"
    serviceClass="com.adelco.webservice.ServiceDocs" wsdlURL="wsdl/wsdl03.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref component-id="inInterceptorBean" />
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref component-id="outInterceptorBean" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref component-id="outFaultInterceptorBean" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Allesandro has said, the chain would unwind on failure.

You could've added an onException clause:

```
onException(ValidationException.class)
  .log("Outbound message: ${body}");

from("cxf:bean:endpointDocs01?loggingFeatureEnabled=true")
.to("direct:CBR") 
.transform().method(WebServiceUtils.class,"response()")
.log("Outbound message: ${body}");
```